# How to avoid duplicates in clickhouse table?

Tags: clickhouse

I have created table and trying to insert the values multiple time to check the duplicates. I can see duplicates are inserting. Is there a way to avoid duplicates in clickhouse table?

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample.tmp_api_logs ( id UInt32,  EventDate Date) 
ENGINE = MergeTree(EventDate, id, (EventDate,id), 8192);

insert into sample.tmp_api_logs values(1,'2018-11-23'),(2,'2018-11-23');
insert into sample.tmp_api_logs values(1,'2018-11-23'),(2,'2018-11-23');

select * from sample.tmp_api_logs;
/*
┌─id─┬──EventDate─┐
│  1 │ 2018-11-23 │
│  2 │ 2018-11-23 │
└────┴────────────┘
┌─id─┬──EventDate─┐
│  1 │ 2018-11-23 │
│  2 │ 2018-11-23 │
└────┴────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: I just repeat that guys wrote in their answers: the deduplication is provided any *Replicated{_/Summing/..}MergeTree*-engine when inserting the same data block as before. It was extended the output format of *system.table_engines* by adding the extra columns including *supports_deduplication* - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/8830 - it helps to survey all engine and their key-abilities.

Comment: FYI: there is PR (https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/8467) to support deduplication on MergeTree-table. Hope soon it be available.

Answer (score 11):

Most likely `ReplacingMergeTree` is what you need as long as duplicate records duplicate primary keys. You can also try out other `MergeTree` engines for more actions when replicate record is encountered. `FINAL` keyword can be used when doing queries to ensure uniquity.

Answer (score 7):

If raw data does not contain duplicates and they might appear only during retries of INSERT INTO, there's a deduplication feature in [**Replicated**MergeTree](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/replication/). To make it work you should retry inserts of exactly the same batches of data (same set of rows in same order). You can use different replica for these retries and data block will still be inserted only once as block hashes are shared between replicas via ZooKeeper.

Otherwise, you should deduplicate data externally before inserts to ClickHouse or clean up duplicates asynchronously with [ReplacingMergeTree or ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/replacingmergetree/).