# clickhouse how to guarantee one data row per a pk(sorting key)?

Tags: sql-update, unique, primary-key, clickhouse

I am struggling with clickhouse to keep unique data row per a PK.

I choose this Column base DB to express statistics data quickly and very satisfied with its speed. However, got some duplicated data issue here.

The test table looks like...

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    `uid`                String COMMENT 'User ID',
    `name`              String COMMENT 'name'
) ENGINE ReplacingMergeTree(uid)
ORDER BY uid
PRIMARY KEY uid;
```

Let's presume that I am going to use this table to join for display names(`name` field in this table). However, I can insert many data as I want in same PK(Sorting key).

For Example

```
INSERT INTO test2
(uid, name) VALUES ('1', 'User1');
INSERT INTO test2
(uid, name) VALUES ('1', 'User2');
INSERT INTO test2
(uid, name) VALUES ('1', 'User3');
SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE uid = '1';
```

Now, I can see 3 rows with same sorting key. Is there any way to make key unique, at least, prevent insert if the key exists?

Let's think about below scenario

tables and data are

```
CREATE TABLE blog (
    `blog_id` String,
    `blog_writer` String
) ENGINE MergeTree
ORDER BY tuple();


CREATE TABLE statistics (
    `date` UInt32,
    `blog_id` String,
    `read_cnt` UInt32,
    `like_cnt` UInt32
) ENGINE MergeTree
ORDER BY tuple();


INSERT INTO blog (blog_id, blog_writer) VALUES ('1', 'name1');
INSERT INTO blog (blog_id, blog_writer) VALUES ('2', 'name2');

INSERT INTO statistics(date, blog_id, read_cnt, like_cnt) VALUES (202007, '1', 10, 20);
INSERT INTO statistics(date, blog_id, read_cnt, like_cnt) VALUES (202008, '1', 20, 0);
INSERT INTO statistics(date, blog_id, read_cnt, like_cnt) VALUES (202009, '1', 3, 1);
INSERT INTO statistics(date, blog_id, read_cnt, like_cnt) VALUES (202008, '2', 11, 2);
```

And here is summing query

```
SELECT
    b.writer,
    a.read_sum,
    a.like_sum
FROM
     (
         SELECT
            blog_id,
            SUM(read_cnt) as read_sum,
            SUM(like_cnt) as like_sum
         FROM statistics
         GROUP BY blog_id
     ) a JOIN
     (
         SELECT blog_id, blog_writer as writer FROM blog
     ) b
    ON a.blog_id = b.blog_id;
```

At this moment it works fine, but if there comes a new low like

```
INSERT INTO statistics(date, blog_id, read_cnt, like_cnt) VALUES (202008, '1', 60, 0);
```

What I expected is update low and sum of the "name1"'`read_sum` is `73`. but it shows `93` since it allows duplicated insert.

Is there any way to

- prevent duplicated insert
- or set unique guaranteed PK in table

Thanks.

Comment: consider to use [FINAL modifier](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from/#select-from-final) in FROM clause

Comment: at this moment *eventually* deduplication is provided by [Replicated*-engines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53702158/303298)

Comment: @vladimir Thanks for the comment. You may add an answer post so I could check yours as an answer and close.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that comes to mind is `ReplacingMergeTree`. It won't guarantee absence of duplication right away, but it it will do so eventually. As docs state:

> Data deduplication occurs only during a merge. Merging occurs in the
> background at an unknown time, so you can’t plan for it. Some of the
> data may remain unprocessed.

Another approach that i personally use is introducing another column named, say, `_ts` - a timestamp when row was inserted. This lets you track changes and with help of clickhouse's beautiful `limit by` you can easily get last version of a row for given pk.

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
    `uid`               String COMMENT 'User ID',
    `name`              String COMMENT 'name',
    `_ts`               DateTime
) ENGINE MergeTree(uid)
ORDER BY uid;
```

Select would look like this:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM test2 ORDER BY _ts DESC LIMIT 1 BY uid;
```

In fact, you don't need a pk, just specify any row/rows in `limit by` that you need rows to be unique by.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `ReplacingMergeTree` which runs deduplication asynchronously, so you can have temporarily duplicated rows with the same pk, you can use `CollapsingMergeTree` or `VersionedCollapsingMergeTree`.

With `CollapsingMergeTree` you could do something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE statistics (
    `date` UInt32,
    `blog_id` String,
    `read_cnt` UInt32,
    `like_cnt` UInt32,
    `sign` Int8

) ENGINE CollapsingMergeTree(sign)
ORDER BY tuple()
PRIMARY KEY blog_id;
```

The only caveat is on every insert of a duplicated PK you have to cancel the previous register, something like this:

```sql
# first insert
INSERT INTO statistics(date, blog_id, read_cnt, like_cnt, sign) VALUES (202008, '1', 20, 0, 1);
```

```sql
# cancel previous insert and insert the new one
INSERT INTO statistics(date, blog_id, read_cnt, like_cnt, sign) VALUES (202008, '1', 20, 0, -1);
INSERT INTO statistics(date, blog_id, read_cnt, like_cnt, sign) VALUES (202008, '1', 11, 2, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a solution for the problem, but at least I detour above problem in this way in the perspective of business.

Since clickhouse officially does not support modification of table data.(They provide `ALTER TABLE ... UPDATE | DELETE`, but eventually those will rewrite the table) I split the table into small multiple partitions(In my case, 1 partition has about 50,000 data) and if duplicated data comes, 1) drop the partition 2) re-insert data again. In above case, I alway execute `ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION` statement before insert.

I also have tried `ReplacingMergeTree`, but data duplication still occurred.(Maybe I do not understand how to use the table but I gave a single sorting key - and when I insert duplicated data there are multiple data in same sorting key)

Comment: You can force the deduplication with `FINAL` keyword